# GitPython list branches, if they match a certain name pattern, delete

Tags: python, git, gitpython

**Goal:** Iterate through remote repo's branches and delete them if they match a certain name pattern, such as:

refs/changes/*

refs/for/*

refs/rewrite/*

refs/delete/*

**What I have done:**

```
from git import Repo

repo_path = "C:\mypath.git"
r = Repo(repo_path)
ref_list = r.refs
deletion_list = []

for ref in ref_list:
    if ref.startswith("refs/changes/"):
        deletion_list.append(ref)

    print(deletion_list)
```

**Error:** SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What should I do to eliminate this error and delete the brances that matches the pattern above?

Comment: "*'url_of_repo_here'*" GitPython can only work with local repositories. The URL must be a path to the local directory or a `file:///` URL. Is it?

Comment: @phd - Edited the post.. so I cannot work with a GitHub URL I take it? If so, suppose I somehow cloned it to local and working with the local folder, what would the code look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitpython%5D+clone

Comment: `Error: NameError: name 'r' is not defined` This code cannot produce that error.  Please post the real code, and the _full_ error traceback message.

Comment: I made some improvements to the code, updated it.

Comment: Please update the question to include the _full_ error traceback message.

Comment: it is the FULL error message, I am sorry there is no other details. I am trying to convert refs to strings but they are gitpython references.

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
for ref in ref_list:
    if ref.startswith("refs/changes/"):
        deletion_list.append(ref)
```

try:

```
for ref in ref_list:
    if "refs/changes/" in ref.name:
        deletion_list.append(ref)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read How to Answer and edit your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.